Fiber sequence and path mapping space
For the simplicial ring morphism $A\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} A\rightarrow A//f$, consider the underlying space morphism, which is a fiber sequence, and we still denote it as $A\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} A\rightarrow A//f$. In the lemma 3.15 of the paper I read, there is an isomorphism induced by this fiber sequence: 
Here is my try on its proof:
Here we can actually drop all the simplicial things and just consider the $f$ as an endomorphism between topological space $A$. If we denote $P_{g}(A)=Fun(I,A)$ where we take the interval $I$with base point at $0$ and $A$ with base point at $g$, thus points in $P_{g}(A)$ are the pathes starting at the point $g$, then and the fiber of this 'path mapping space' along the morphism $f$, $\text{Fib}_{g}(A\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}A)$ is exactly the pullback:
And by using the condition of the 'fiber sequence', we have the composition of pullback square:.
And for the left hand side of the isomorphism, which is the pullback 
Thus to prove the isomorphism in the lemma, it suffices to show that $P_{g}(A)\cong P_{g}(A//f)$, but I guess this is not that true, so what is the right way to show the isomorphism by the fiber sequence? I believe I need to use some techniques along with this fiber sequence, any hint on this is very welcome.

These are all homotopy pullbacks (or pullbacks in an $\infty$-category). Both $P_g(A)$ and $P_g(A//f)$ are contractible, so the resulting (homotopy) pullbacks are equivalent.

@VincentBoelens But the fiber sequence of the underlying spaces:$A\rightarrow A\rightarrow A//f$ is a strict pullback (or fiber), right?  And under the context of homotopy pullbacks, I think the ‘isomorphism’ we get in the end should be ‘weak homotopy equivalence’, is that true?

The authors are working in $\infty$-categories, so all pullbacks/fibers are actually homotopy pullbacks/fibers.

The authors of the linked paper work in $\infty$-categories, so all pullbacks and fiber sequences are actually homotopy pullbacks and homotopy fiber sequences (or more precisely, modeled by them) and isomorphism means (homotopy) equivalence. Now $P_g(A)$ and $P_g(A//f)$ are both contractible (contract a loop $\alpha$ to the constant loop at $\alpha(0)=g$), in particular they are equivalent, so the resulting homotopy pullbacks $\mathrm{Map}_{A//f}(g,0)$ and $\mathrm{Fib}_g(A\xrightarrow{f}A)$ are equivalent.
However, it is more convenient to work directly in the $\infty$-category of spaces. By definition $\mathrm{Map}_{A//f}(g,0)$ is the pullback of $\ast\xrightarrow{0} A//f \xleftarrow{g}\ast$ and $\mathrm{Fib}_g(A\xrightarrow{f}A)$ is the pullback of $A\xrightarrow{f}A\xleftarrow{g}\ast$.
Since $A\to A\to A//f$ is a fiber sequence, in the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Fib}_g(A\xrightarrow{f}A) @>>> \ast \\
@VVV @VVgV \\
A @>f>> A\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\ast @>0>> A//f
\end{CD}$$
the inner squares are pullbacks, hence also the outer square is a pullback.

Let me also point out that in the ($\infty$-)category of spaces the point is not a zero object, this is only true in the ($\infty$-)category of pointed spaces.

Thanks for your great answer, I just want to confirm that in the context of your answer, we are working in the category of spaces instead of pointed space, right? Are you implicitly using the ’point out ‘ in the remark for your answer?  I am afraid that I probably lose some crucial things here?

Yes, unpointed spaces. I made my comment since you used the notation for the zero object in the pullbacks, but you can only have pointed maps $\ast\xrightarrow{0}\to A$ and $\ast\xrightarrow{g} A$ if $0$ and $g$ lie in the same path component and I think this is not what the authors want.

I get it, thanks so much.
